# Filter numpy array by comparing elements to elements in prior row without looping

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am very new to Python and NumPy and have spent a couple of days searching for an answer to this question.

Consider the following 2D array of stock prices with columns 0 through 3 being the open, high, low and close prices with each row (0-6) being subsequent days.

```
      O      H      L      C
0 | 43.97  43.97  43.75  43.94
1 | 43.97  44.25  43.97  44.25
2 | 44.22  44.38  44.12  44.34
3 | 44.41  44.84  44.38  44.81
4 | 44.97  45.09  44.47  45.00
5 | 44.97  45.06  44.72  44.97
6 | 44.97  45.12  44.91  44.97
```

For this example I will use O, H, L, or C to represent columns 0-3, and 0, 1 or 2 to represent a row *offset (backwards)* for O, H, L  or C.

H2 would mean the value of column H two rows back, and C0 would mean the value of column C in the current row.  So in row 3, H2 would equal 44.25 and C0 would equal 44.81.

I would like to get the rows from this type of array using conditions that effectively equate to the logical statement C0 > H2 or similar statement. Ultimately I want to include multiple comparisons like this to return a subset of the array rows.

Is it possible to do this without looping through the array?

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting `H[3:]`, to get an array of "H" values three rows back.  What do you want to do for values at the end of the series?  Have a shorter array? Set the to zero? NaN? Wrap back to the start of the array? (For the latter option, have a look at `np.roll`.)

Comment: Using my example array and my example condition I would want to return all values in rows 2, 3, 4 and 5 because 44.34 > 43.97 and 44.81 > 44.25 and 45.00 > 44.38 and 44.97 > 44.84, but 44.97 < 45.09.  In my condition C0 > H2, C means column C and 0 always represent the current row and H2 means column H and 2 means I want to look 2 rows back.  I could also have a comparison like H0 > H1 meaning today's H is greater than yesterday's H.  The numbers are not indexes of the array but positions of rows relative to one another.

Comment: Are you wedded to using `numpy`?  When you're working with named columns -- and if you're working with OHLC timeseries data -- [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) will make a lot of things easier.

Comment: If the data is in array `M`, shape `(7,4)`, `C0=M[:2,3]`, and `H2=M[:2,1]`, `C0>H2` would be a boolean of length 5.  `M[:2,:][C0>H2]` selected rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you're wanting to do things like (to use your example of "C0 > H2"):

```
values = data[2:][C[2:] > H[:-2]]
```

However, you can easily see how this becomes repetitive.

Therefore, it's easiest to make new sequences of "H2", etc that are the same length as the rest of your data.  When you do this, you need some way to indicate which values are invalid or insert valid values.

There's more than one way to handle this (e.g. different boundary conditions, masked arrays, etc).  For example, you could decide to extend the series with the last valid value, instead.

For the moment, because you have floating point arrays, let's insert NaN's into the missing positions.  That way any comparisons will return `False`.

In that case, you'd do something like:

```
H2 = np.pad(H[:-2], (2, 0), mode='constant', constant_values=(np.nan,))
```

or more generally:

```
def shift(data, amount):
    data = data[:-amount]
    pad = (amount, 0)
    return np.pad(data, pad, mode='constant', constant_values=(np.nan,))
```

That way you can directly compare things. E.g. `H[H > shift(H, 2)]`

---

Also, as DSM mentioned, look into using `pandas` for this.  It will make your life much easier in general, and the equivalent expression would be:

```
df[df.C > df.H.shift(2)]
```

---

### Detailed Explanation

Let's break that down a bit.

If we start with the series `x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then `x[:-2]` will give us `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(6)
x2 = x[2:]
```

However, if we wanted to compare it with some other sequence of the same original length, we have a problem, as `x` is now two items shorter than the other sequence.

```
y = np.linspace(-2, -3, 6)
```

and comparing them will raise a ValueError, as they're not the same length:

```
In [4]: x2 > y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-eec160476995> in <module>()
----> 1 x2 > y

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4) (6)
```

Furthermore, we don't want to compare the first value of the new "shifted" x with the first value of the original sequence.  We want to compare the first item of the "shifted" sequence with the *third* item of the original sequence.

To do this, we need to slice the other sequence as well.  E.g. `y[2:]`:

```
In [5]: x2 > y[2:]
Out[5]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

However, this is a bit clunky.  We need to know how much `x2` has been shifted by to use it properly.  It's much easier to insert new values into `x2` so that we can index directly with it.

In my original example, I used `np.pad` to insert `NaN`s at the start of the array.

```
x2 = np.pad(x[:-2], (2, 0), mode='constant', constant_values=(np.nan,))
```

The necessary arguments to `pad` are a touch awkward in this case. If you'd prefer not to use `np.pad`, you could also do something similar to the following:

```
x2 = np.hstack([2 * [np.nan], x[:-2]])
```

The big advantage of either of these approaches is that we have arrays of the same length, and any comparisons against `np.nan` will be False.

For example:

```
In [9]: x2
Out[9]: array([ nan,  nan,   0.,   1.,   2.,   3.])

In [10]: x2 > -np.inf
Out[10]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

This makes it easy to directly compare with `y`:

```
In [11]: y
Out[11]: array([-2. , -2.2, -2.4, -2.6, -2.8, -3. ])

In [12]: x2 > y
Out[12]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

---

### Examples

As a more complete example:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    data = np.array([[43.97, 43.97, 43.75, 43.94],
                     [43.97, 44.25, 43.97, 44.25],
                     [44.22, 44.38, 44.12, 44.34],
                     [44.41, 44.84, 44.38, 44.81],
                     [44.97, 45.09, 44.47, 45.00],
                     [44.97, 45.06, 44.72, 44.97],
                     [44.97, 45.12, 44.91, 44.97]])
    O, H, L, C = data.T

    values = data[C > shift(H, 2)]
    print values

def shift(data, amount):
    data = data[:-amount]
    pad = (amount, 0)
    return np.pad(data, pad, mode='constant', constant_values=(np.nan,))

main()
```

`values` is then:

```
[[ 44.22  44.38  44.12  44.34]
 [ 44.41  44.84  44.38  44.81]
 [ 44.97  45.09  44.47  45.  ]
 [ 44.97  45.06  44.72  44.97]]
```

---

And just to show a `pandas` version, as well:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[43.97, 43.97, 43.75, 43.94],
                   [43.97, 44.25, 43.97, 44.25],
                   [44.22, 44.38, 44.12, 44.34],
                   [44.41, 44.84, 44.38, 44.81],
                   [44.97, 45.09, 44.47, 45.00],
                   [44.97, 45.06, 44.72, 44.97],
                   [44.97, 45.12, 44.91, 44.97]],
                  columns=['O', 'H', 'L', 'C'])

values = df[df.C > df.H.shift(2)]
print values
```

Which yields:

```
       O      H      L      C
2  44.22  44.38  44.12  44.34
3  44.41  44.84  44.38  44.81
4  44.97  45.09  44.47  45.00
5  44.97  45.06  44.72  44.97
```

Comment: Joe, thanks so much for your solution and detailed explanation.  Since I'm just figuring this stuff out I'm definitely not married to numpy.  I'll check into pandas.

Comment: @ckeblack - It's best to learn both `pandas` and `numpy`.  (Or, rather, you can't really learn pandas without knowing/picking up a reasonable amount of numpy.)  `pandas` is specialized for "spreadsheet-like" data.  `numpy` is focused more on the building blocks and general N-dimensional arrays.  They're complimentary, rather than competing (`pandas` is built on top of `numpy`).

Comment: I jumped into `pandas` and began the next logical step in my project, which is to create dynamic conditions by replacing `df.C > df.H.shift(2)` with a value that is constructed on the fly since the comparison will not always be the same and there will be more than two elements in the comparison.  Is it possible to replace the static condition with  a variable that contains the logic?  Here is an example of a condition that I might use.  `(H > C) & (C > shift(H, 1)) & (shift(H, 1) > shift(C, 1))`

Comment: @ckeblack - You can access columns of a `DataFrame` by indexing them with the column name. E.g. `df['C'] > df['H'].shift(2)`.   This will work just as well if you do `df[column_name]`, where `column_name` is your variable.